# Marking menu button by opened url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website with `nav` menu.

```
<nav>
    <h1>Menu:</h1> <br>
    <a href="/tests/add-new-test-link">Add link</a>
    <a href="/tests/run-tests">Run tests</a>
    <a href="/tests/reports-history">Test reports history</a>
    <a href="/tests/links-list">Links list</a>
</nav>
```

Now, depending on the opened page I want to add a class with some styles to the pressed button. So the users will know on which page they actually are. Since pressing the button is reloading the website, I want to transform the button after the page is loaded, on the basis of the currently opened URL.

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
var hrefCheck = currentUrl.split('/').pop();

$("nav").find("a").each(function() {
  if ($(this).indexOf(hrefCheck)) {
     $(this).addClass("focused");
  }
});
```

In the above script, the currently opened URL is being cut and equated to the `href` of the buttons links. The link `href` that matches the opened url should get the class added.

ERROR:-

> "indexOf() is not a function"

This error I am currently getting. What is happening?

Comment: Try `$(this).attr("href").indexOf(hrefCheck)`

Comment: Should be `$(this).attr('href').indexOf(...`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `.attr("href")` and also check like this `!= -1`

`$(this).attr("href").indexOf(hrefCheck) != -1`

If the `hrefCheck` don't exist in `$(this).attr("href")` then it would return -1

```js
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
var hrefCheck = currentUrl.split('/').pop();

$("nav").find("a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf(hrefCheck) != -1) {
        $(this).addClass("focused");
    }
});
```

```css
.focused{color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <h1>Menu:</h1> <br>
    <a href="/tests/js">Add link</a>
    <a href="/tests/run-tests">Run tests</a>
    <a href="/tests/reports-history">Test reports history</a>
    <a href="/tests/links-list">Links list</a>
</nav>
```